# Ending of Exit: Sacred Temple

Tags: escape-the-room

In Exit: The Sacred Temple, one of the jigsaw entries into the escape room board game family the 'last' riddle asks you if you want to try to save the jug from the collapsing temple.

As there's still a riddle document in the box then obviously we're going to have a go. Opening the final booklet gives you a cut and stick photo opportunity and a happy ending storyline.

But no puzzle to solve.

Did we miss something?

Comment: I don't know what SGSE policy is on spoilers (something for me to learn) but you might be better contacting the games publisher to check if you missed something.  That way anyone else who might play this game doesn't find out anything in advance they don't want to know.

Comment: @StartPlayer I hope anyone worries about spoilers would avoid pages headed 'Ending of'. But I understand the concern.

Comment: @Jonita I agree entirely!  As I say I don't know what BGSE policy on spoilers is.   I often tweet stuff about Gloomhaven and no idea how old something has to be before I can tweet freely.